# How to fix permission denied when I try to connect via SSH to my ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, authentication

When I try to connect to my Ubuntu server hosted on AWS I get "Permission Denied".

`ssh -v ...` gets me this:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 52.22.60.11 [52.22.60.11] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 52.22.60.11:22 as 'admin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:BkkfDekRz+v2Q7D8KR+WUtSR8asoqnAyvQPJyLubaUI
debug1: Host '52.22.60.11' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/RubenBerkhout/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: You have not provided a valid private key for the server and _publickey_ is the only one method to access it...

Answer (score 1):

AWS forces private-key authentication. They don't allow only user/pass auth.

---

You have do:

```
ssh -i private-key.pem user@server-ip
```

Substituting in your information, obviously.

If you don't already have a `.pem` file, you can download it from the AWS control panel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I try it get the following.. 192:pemfiles RubenBerkhout$ ssh -i unifi02062016.pem admin@52.22.60.11
Permission denied (publickey).
192:pemfiles RubenBerkhout$

Comment: @RubenBerkhout - Can you run it again with `-v` and post the output?

Comment: OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname private-key.pem: nodename nor servname provided, or not known